# RegEx for extracting url parameters

Tags: javascript, regex, url, parameters

I need to extract url parameters from the following string

```
?theAccount=someData&theToken=sometoken&mediaId=someid
```

so I want `someData sometoken someid`

here is the function I am using

```
function getParams( name ) {
            var str = window.location.search;
            var r = new RegExp("/(^\?|&+)"+name+"(\=)/");
            var result =  r.exec(str);
            if (r) { return result; }
            return "";

        }
```

called like so `getParams(theAccount);`

But it's not working and keeps "invalid regular expression". Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: Could you provide sample input/output? Not sure what 'theAccount' is supposed to be.